# How to set the default style to a React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

The React component is great because it lets us define our own tags, which can be more powerful than the original ones.

Currently I am only using the React component to define the HTML structure, and setting the className of each tag to let the style sheet modify its appearance. Is there a way to give a default style to components without using inline CSS?

One idea I have is to add one CSS file associated with one component, or add a  tag directly in the jsx file for each component, then compile the CSS or jsx to put all the CSS in one file and added it in  part.

Comment: I do not think it is a clear solution to that atm. BUT at react conf in january they talked about their new "inline"-styling scheme which came with React-Native. With that you can create javascript objects which holds the styles. ```StyleSheet.create({ 'myComponent' : { margin: 5, padding: 5 }});```
This lets you keep the component CSS apart and you could then add the css to your component structure.

Comment: Is this the inline style? I think it's better to let the user have the privilege to modified the style of the component via the style sheet.  This will let us build components with beautiful UI as well as the Scalability.

Comment: Its inline style, but you separate it in a .js file instead of .css. This means it almost has the same purpose as a stylesheet. The user would only need to alter one file. Here is an example from a React-Native project im working on: https://jsfiddle.net/0aqgxr5v/ PS: it works with React as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easily expressed with [inline style](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/inline-styles.html) approach in React:

```
var compStyle = {
  color: 'white',
  backgroundImage: 'url(' + imgUrl + ')',
  margin: 5
};

React.render(<div style={compStyle}>Component</div>, mountNode);
```

Comment: Nah, it's better to not using inline style because I want others to have the ability to modified the style via css.

Comment: consider that A has written a component with a beautiful UI, and B wants to use this component, somehow B wants to change some part of the style via css, but if A used inline css so there's no chance for B to modify that via css.

Comment: That is unrelated to the original question, but it is easy to pass new styles object into component via props and merge them with the default styles. So you can modify default styles with 'inline approach'.